# Linked Server in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

Newbie. Be gentle (or parental)

I have a query that I'm trying to build for a report. From instance `AWDATA` (SQL Server 2008), I have a linked server `GGIAPP01` (which contains an ACCPAC database).

When I run the following, with lines commented out, all is well.

When I uncomment, I get no argument, the query runs, `BW_AK.NR_RECHNUNG, BW_AP.ID, BW_AS.POS_NR` are returned as `NULL`.

Also `BW_AUFTR_KOPF` is one to many `BW_AUFTR_POS`, and `BW_AUFTR_POS` is one to many `BW_AUFTR_STKL`, but the record count remains the same regardless.

I suspect the first (BW) join is the culprit, but I'm not sure how to verify exactly.  Without the CAST, I get a type mismatch, as `IDINVC` is `char(22)` and `NR_RECHNUNG` is `int`.

Any feedback is appreciated.  This is a new domain for me!

Thank you,

Matt

```
declare @FiscalPeriod integer = 03, @FiscalYear integer = 2014

select
      AROBP.IDINVC,  AROBP.AMTPAYMTC, AROBP.TRANSTYPE, AROBP.TRXTYPE,
      AROBP.FISCPER, AROBP.FISCYR,    AROBP.DATEBTCH,  AROBP.IDCUST,
      ARCUS.NAMECUST,
      ARIBH.TEXTTRX, ARIBH.DATEINVC, ARIBH.AMTINVCTOT,
      ARSAP.NAMEEMPL,
--          BW_AK.NR_RECHNUNG,
--          BW_AP.ID,
--          BW_AS.POS_NR
from      GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.AROBP       AROBP
left join GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.ARCUS       ARCUS on AROBP.IDCUST    = ARCUS.IDCUST
left join GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.ARIBH       ARIBH on AROBP.IDINVC    = ARIBH.IDINVC
left join GGIAPP01.GGI.dbo.ARSAP       ARSAP on ARCUS.CODESLSP1 = ARSAP.CODESLSP
--left join GGIMAIN.SYSADM.BW_AUFTR_KOPF BW_AK on AROBP.IDINVC = CAST(BW_AK.NR_RECHNUNG as
--varchar)
--left join GGIMAIN.SYSADM.BW_AUFTR_POS  BW_AP on BW_AK.ID = BW_AP.ID
--left join GGIMAIN.SYSADM.BW_AUFTR_STKL BW_AS on BW_AP.ID = BW_AS.ID and BW_AP.POS_NR =
--BW_AS.POS_NR
where     AROBP.IDINVC NOT LIKE 'PY%'
  AND AROBP.FISCPER = @FiscalPeriod
  AND AROBP.FISCYR  = @FiscalYear
order by  AROBP.IDINVC, ARSAP.NAMEEMPL, AROBP.IDCUST
```

Comment: Not related to your question, my feedback is to use openquery.  The reason is, with the syntax you are using, all the records from the linked server tables come into sql server first.  The where clause is applied afterwards.

Comment: It sounds like what you're saying is that the query returns without error, but the data is not as expected.      
Is that right?

If that is the case, it seems like this isn't a problem setting up the linked server.  If it can't find the server or the tables, it will let you know.
It's probably a data or t-sql design question.

Does that make sense?

Comment: To debug, don't enable all 3 joins at once. Comment in the BW_AK table and leave the others commented out. NULLs are expected behaviour in a left join when there is no matching row, so i think the select never finds a matching BW_AK.NR_RECHNUNG to the AROBP.IDINVCs. Try `select IDINVC from AROBP` and `select CAST(BW_AK.NR_RECHNUNG as varchar) from GGIMAIN.SYSADM.BW_AUFTR_KOPF`. Do corresponding rows look the same? Or is there some subtle difference?

Comment: Just to confirm, you are sure that the data in AROBP.IDINVC is going to match with the data in BW_AUFTR_KOPF.NR_RECHNUNG ?  You have looked at both of those columns and you can see rows that should match?

Comment: Thank you all.  Everything appears to be cooperative linking, but what was documented as type INT turns out to actually be type FLOAT.

So AROBP.IDINVC is char(22) and BW_AK.NR_RECHNUNG is FLOAT.  The indicated CAST statement has a bunch of trailing 0's.

Trying various combinations, when I change the conversion to
CAST((CAST(NR_RECHNUNG as INT)) as CHAR(22)) as INVINTCHAR,
SELECT displays just lovely, but the JOIN doesn't like it at all.

Any thoughts about a workaround?